# Resource usage of ThreadPool RegisterWaitForSingleObject

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, resources, threadpool

I am writing a server application which processes request from multiple clients. For the processing of requests I am using the *threadpool*.

Some of these requests modify a database record, and I want to restrict the access to that specific record to one *threadpool* thread at a time. For this I am using named *semaphores* (other processes are also accessing these records).
For each new request that wants to modify a record, the thread should wait in line for its turn.

And this is where the question comes in:
As I don't want the threadpool to fill up with threads waiting for access to a record, I found the *RegisterWaitForSingleObject* method in the *threadpool*.
But when I read the documentation ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) under the section *Remarks*:

> New wait threads are created automatically when required. ...

Does this mean that the *threadpool* will fill up with *wait-threads*? And how does this affect the performance of the *threadpool*?

Any other suggestions to boost performance is more than welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: RWFSO is created specifically so that thread pool doesn't run out of threads.

Comment: @GregC so what about this wait-thread? Is it one thread for all waiting callbacks, or one for each?

Comment: Like I tried to explain in my answer there will be one thread assigned to service many waiting callbacks. I am not sure what the actual ratio would be, but it definitely would be better than 1-to-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is a viable option. In the absence of more specific details I do not think I can offer other tangible options. However, let me try to illustrate why I think your current solution is, at the very least, based on sound theory.

Lets say you have 64 requests that came in simultaneously. It is reasonable to assume that the thread pool could dispatch each one of those requests to a thread immediately. So you might have 64 threads that immediately begin processing. Now lets assume that the mutex has already been acquired by another thread and it is held for a really long time. That means those 64 threads will be blocked for a long time waiting for the thread that currently owns the mutex to release it. That means those 64 threads are wasted on doing nothing.

On the other hand, if you choose to use `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` as opposed to using a blocking call to wait for the mutex to be released then you can immediately release those 64 waiting threads (work items) and allow them to be put back into the pool. If I were to implement my own version of `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` then I would use the `WaitHandle.WaitAny` method which allows me to specify up to 64 handles (I did not randomly choose 64 for the number of requests afterall) in a single blocking method call. I am not saying it would be easy, but I could replace my 64 waiting threads for only a single thread from the pool. I do not know how Microsoft implemented the `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` method, but I am guessing they did it in a manner that is at least as efficient as my strategy. To put this another way, you should be able to reduce the number of pending work items in the thread pool by at least a factor of 64 by using `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`.

So you see, your solution is based on sound theory. I am not saying that your solution is optimal, but I do believe your concern is unwarranted in regards to the specific question asked.

Comment: Thank you! :)  
I am not yet quite sure of how I will implement the solution to this problem in the final application. But for now I at least have a better understanding of how the `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` method works.

Comment: Documentation says that behind the scenes, there's a Win32 WaitForMultipleObjects happening.  It also says that you should not try to pulse the sync object that you provide yourself, since the synchronization object that lets the work items to run is a different one.  Use a DuplicateHandle function...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9f75h7a.aspx

Comment: And to reinforce what we're talking about, it says "the wait thread", implying that there's only one thread that blocks.

Comment: This may be relevant to the discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131807/is-maximum-wait-objects-really-64

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should let the database do its own synchronization.  All you need to do is to ensure that you're sync'ed within your process.

Interlocked class might be a premature optimization that is too complex to implement.  I would recommend using higher-level sync objects, such as ReaderWriterLockSlim.  Or better yet, a Monitor.

Comment: How do you propose I do this?
The problem is that the request need to do some operations on a specific record in the database, but not all operations can be done in one query. Therefore I need to lock down the record until one thread is complete, so that it is not modified while the thread is doing its thing.

Comment: Any way to normalize the database so that each record contains a logically separate information?  This might help with the locking.

Answer (score 0):

An approach to this problem that I've used before is to have the first thread that gets one of these work items be responsible for any other ones that occur while it's processing the work item(s),  This is done by queueing the work items then dropping into a critical section to process the queue.  Only the 'first' thread will drop into the critical section. If a thread can't get the critical section, it'll leave and let the thread already operating in the critical section handle the queued object.

It's really not very complicated - the only thing that might not be obvious is that when leaving the critical section, the processing thread has to do it in a way that doesn't potentially leave a late-arriving workitem on the queue. Basically, the 'processing' critical section lock has to be released while holding the queue lock.  If not for this one requirement, a synchronized queue would be sufficient, and the code would really be simple!

Pseudo code:

```
// `workitem` is an object that contains the database modification request
//
// `queue` is a Queue<T> that can hold these workitem requests
//
//  `processing_lock` is an object use to provide a lock
//      to indicate a thread is processing the queue


// any number of threads can call this function, but only one
//  will end up processing all the workitems.
//
// The other threads will simply drop the workitem in the queue
//  and leave
void threadpoolHandleDatabaseUpdateRequest(workitem)
{
    // put the workitem on a queue
    Monitor.Enter(queue.SyncRoot);
    queue.Enqueue(workitem);
    Monitor.Exit(queue.SyncRoot);

    bool doProcessing;
    Monitor.TryEnter(processing_queue, doProcessing);
    if (!doProcessing) {
        // another thread has the processing lock, it'll
        //  handle the workitem
        return;
    }

    for (;;) {

        Monitor.Enter(queue.SyncRoot);
        if (queue.Count() == 0) {
            // done processing the queue

            // release locks in an order that ensures 
            // a workitem won't get stranded on the queue

            Monitor.Exit(processing_queue);
            Monitor.Exit(queue.SyncRoot);
            break;
        }

        workitem = queue.Dequeue();
        Monitor.Exit(queue.SyncRoot);

        // this will get the database mutex, do the update and release 
        //  the database mutex
        doDatabaseModification(workitem); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ThreadPool creates a wait thread for ~64 waitable objects.

Good comments are here: [Thread.sleep vs Monitor.Wait vs RegisteredWaitHandle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381771/thread-sleep-vs-monitor-wait-vs-registeredwaithandle)