# C++ Wait all threads to finish

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, events, wait

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <wtypes.h>
typedef unsigned int (__stdcall * THREAD_FUN_TYPE)(void *);

int ThreadIp(void* param)
{
    while(true)
    {
        printf("I'm runing!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int iThreadNum=100;
    HANDLE* phThreads = new HANDLE[iThreadNum];
    for (int i=0;i<iThreadNum;++i)
    {
        phThreads[i]=(HANDLE*)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0,  (THREAD_FUN_TYPE)ThreadIp,NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }

    int nIndex = ::WaitForMultipleObjects(iThreadNum,phThreads,1,INFINITE);
    printf("End!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I want the program will halt at WaitForMultipleObjects until all thread are **end**(Not until all thread are created successfully).But the program will not halt at WaitForMultipleObjects,while all threads are still running. So I try to use SetEvent,but still the same problem:

```
int iThreadNum=100;
HANDLE* phThreads = new HANDLE[iThreadNum];
for (int i=0;i<iThreadNum;++i)
{
    phThreads[i]=CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE,NULL);
    ResetEvent(phThreads[i]);
}
int nIndex = ::WaitForMultipleObjects(iThreadNum,phThreads,1,INFINITE);
```

Comment: 100 threads is a lot of threads. How many cores has your machine got?

Comment: It has 8 cores.Sorry I have just seen your reply

Comment: It won't run all your threads at once then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you have fewer threads? The [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says you need to do extra work if you have more than `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS`, specifically

> nCount [in] The number of object handles in the array pointed to by
>   lpHandles. The maximum number of object handles is
>   MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS. This parameter cannot be zero.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131807/is-maximum-wait-objects-really-64) for a discussion.

It might be worth checking what the wait function has returned too.

Answer (score 2):

You should wait on the thread handles, not the unrelated events:

Try something like this:

```
 int iThreadNum=100;
 HANDLE* phThreads = new HANDLE[iThreadNum];
 for (int i=0;i<iThreadNum;++i)
 {
     m_iCurThreadNum=i;
     phThreads[i] = _beginthreadex(...);
  }

 int nIndex = ::WaitForMultipleObjects(iThreadNum,phThreads,1,INFINITE);
```

Comment: what kind of failure? Does the program not halt on the ~WaitForMultipleObjects~? Please add prints in the respective thread function, and see if the threads ran in very short periods.

Comment: I've edited the question.I want all threads's work done,then I can do more things.

Answer (score 0):

I would allocate a struct before calling _beginthreadex and pass the pointer to the struct through the threads parameter and have the struct contain a bool which is set by the thread when it's done.

```
struct ThreadStruct{
    bool Done;
    char* ParamData;
    int ParamDataSize;
};

int ThreadIp(void* param)
{
    ThreadStruct* ts = (ThreadStruct*)param;
    while(true)
    {
        printf("I'm runing!\n");
    }
    ts->Done = true;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int iThreadNum=100;
    HANDLE* phThreads = new HANDLE[iThreadNum];
    ThreadStruct* structs = new ThreadStruct[iThreadNum];
    for (int i=0;i<iThreadNum;++i)
    {
        ZeroMemory(structs[i], sizeof(ThreadStruct));
        phThreads[i]=(HANDLE*)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0,  (THREAD_FUN_TYPE)ThreadIp, structs[i], NULL, NULL);
        ResetEvent(phThreads[i]);
    }

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<iThreadNum;){
        if(!structs[i]->Done) i=0;
        else i++;
    }
    printf("End!\n");
    return 0;
}
```